# In R data.table, does chaining with magrittr pipes do harm regarding performance?

Tags: r, data.table, chaining, magrittr

Sometimes I like to (or have to) do chaining, when working on a data.table.

```
library(data.table)

DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)

DT[, .(y, z = v * y)][, lapply(.SD, sum)]
```

However, I could also write the last line, using a pipe, which could be advantageous sometimes (regarding readability/structuring of code):

```
DT[, .(y, z = v * y)] %>% 
  .[, lapply(.SD, sum)]
```

Is the chaining approach using pipes equivalent to chaining without pipes regarding performance (speed, memory usage)?

EDIT: 
I am aware, that chaining using pipes can be slower than non-piping in some situations. But my question is, if `DT[...] %>% .[...]` instead of `DT[...][...]` is such an example (because it could be the case, that there are some internal 'invisible' optimization in `DT[...][...]`, that would be broken in `DT[...] %>% .[...])`.

EDIT2: 
Also I am aware, that using the pipe always produces a slight overhead, which might matter, if a very large number of such operations are performed. But I am interested in the question, which I tried to clarify in above EDIT from an algorithmic perspective (namely the possibility, that an efficient internal optimization is hindered from being applied, due to the use of %>%).

Comment: No, I edited my question for clarification.

Comment: Well, to use pipes you will need to load an extra package so here is a performance set back

Comment: not specifically an answer to your question, but the microbenchmark library is good for answering these kind of questions on your own code https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/microbenchmark/versions/1.4-7/topics/microbenchmark

Comment: @Sotos, this is true, but I was looking for a real 'algorithmic' disadvantage, as described in the edit. This would make a difference, when working with millions of rows with hundreds of columns.

Comment: You are technically adding a new operation when using the pipe so there will be overhead(not much, but it exists). I suggest `dtplyr` if you want to use `tidy` syntax with `data.table`.

Comment: Using pipes is probably always slower. By how much and in which cases it matters the most is an interesting question.